# Retrieve button position relative to control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a grid that contains dynamically created buttons.

I have a selector tool that will select a "rectangle" of buttons and do whatever on them.

I'm stuck at this point, because I'm going down the MVVM route.. but I previously had a list of all the buttons and would do:

```
  var buttonPos = button.TransformToAncestor(someGrid).Transform(new Point(0, 0));
```

Now I do not have the luxury of being able to get all the buttons in my itemscontrol to do that (or at least I don't know how).

This is a section of my XAML.

```
<Grid Name="mainGrid" DockPanel.Dock="Left" MouseDown="MainGrid_MouseDown" MouseUp="MainGrid_MouseUp" MouseMove="MainGrid_MouseMove" Background="Transparent" 
                              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                              MinWidth="{Binding GridWidth}" Height="{Binding GridHeight}">
                            <ItemsControl x:Name="ObjItemControl" ItemsSource="{Binding ObjCompositeCollection}">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                                    <Style>
                                        <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding Row}"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding Column}"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                         VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Name="objGrid" Grid.Row="1" 
                                         Width="{Binding MinWidth, ElementName=mainGrid}" 
                                         Height="{Binding Height, ElementName=mainGrid}"
                                         engine:GridHelper.RowCount="{Binding RowCount}"
                                         engine:GridHelper.ColumnCount="{Binding ColumnCount}" />
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsControl.Resources>
                                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type engine:ObjA}">
                                        <ToggleButton Content="{Binding Id}"
                                                Tag="{Binding Id}"
                                                IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"
                                                Height="{Binding ElementName=ObjItemControl, 
                                            Path=DataContext.ButtonHeightWidth}"
                                                Width="{Binding ElementName=ObjItemControl, 
                                            Path=DataContext.ButtonHeightWidth}"
                                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                                Margin="{Binding ElementName=wellPlateItemControl, 
                                            Path=DataContext.ButtonMarginToUse}"
                                                Padding="2"
                                                PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="Button_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"
                                                PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="Button_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp"
                                                MouseEnter="Button_MouseEnter"
                                                MouseLeave="Button_MouseLeave"
                                                Style="{StaticResource ObjButton}">
                                        </ToggleButton>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type engine:GridLabeller}">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding HeaderName}" Style="{StaticResource GridHeaders}"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.Resources>
                            </ItemsControl>
                            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding RectForMarquee}">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <Canvas/>
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Rectangle Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}"
                                                   Visibility="{Binding Visibility}" 
                                                   Stroke="{StaticResource ResourceKey=SecondaryThemeColour}" 
                                                   StrokeThickness="2" StrokeDashArray="2,1"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl>
                            <!--<Canvas>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="selectionBox" Visibility="Collapsed" Stroke="{StaticResource ResourceKey=SecondaryThemeColour}" StrokeThickness="2" StrokeDashArray="2,1"/>
                            </Canvas>-->
                        </Grid>
```

I want to be able to get all of the ObjA toggle buttons and do that `TransformToAncestor` check... unless there is a better way?

I can also do this in the View code-behind but not sure if this is a bit naughty...

```
    private void MainGrid_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        // Need to find a better way for this...
        List<UIElement> tgInItemControl = new List<UIElement>();
        foreach (var toggleButton in VisualHelperExtensions.FindVisualChildren<ToggleButton>(ObjItemControl))
        {
            tgInItemControl.Add(toggleButton);
        }

        viewModel.MainGrid_MouseUp(tgInItemControl, e);
    }
```

Comment: You recall the 2d array to observablecollection i suggested? You could have used x and y index to work out adjacent cells if you'd used that.

Comment: Hey Andy... I recall you mentioning it but if I'm perfectly honest I didn't understand it too well.... do you have a skeleton example? Why adjacent cells also?

Comment: "Make it an observablecollection of object and add emptyvm for an empty cell, textvm for a textblock, buttonvm for button... Etc. Add a datatemplate for each in the itemscontrol resources. " this part I didn't understand how it would "look" and how the buttonVM would link to the emptyVM to relate its location

Comment: If you have a 3*2 matrix then you need 6 viewmodels. Each is templated into ui inside a 'cell'. Two buttons and 4 empty still means 6 vm. I posted a link to something datatemplates based on type. Look at it again. Define a datatemplate containing a button. Define a class called buttonvm. Associate the firmer with the latter using datatype like in the sample i linked. When an instance of buttonvm is encountered as an item that's datatemplated into a button.